How to pass dynamic value to a FOR loop?
I can do this:
for i in 1 .. (select pays from schema.table_name where pk_id='12' and pk2_id='123')

But it only works for this particular row. How to do it for all rows in the table?
Getting below error for passing without WHERE condition:

ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression


I am using the FOR loop to iterate for the number of payments done. For example, if pays is 50, then for the primary key combination with other fields should iterate 50 rows and this needs to continue for next primary key combination. Etc.

So do you have your answer?

Looping - as requested
There are two distinct syntax variants of PL/pgSQL FOR loops.

One loops through query results (with an implicit cursor).
The other is the "integer variant" that iterates through a given range of integer values.

Seems like you want to nest both.
And you want to use some columns from each row in the inner loop. Simplest with a record variable:
DO
$do$
DECLARE
   _rec record;
   i int;
BEGIN
   -- do it for all (?) rows in table table_name
   -- remember selected columns
   FOR _rec IN
      SELECT pays, pk_id, pk2_id  -- or whatever
      FROM   schema.table_name
      ORDER  BY 1  -- or whatever
   LOOP
      --  do it "pays" times
      FOR i IN 1 .. _rec.pays
      LOOP
         -- do something ...
         RAISE NOTICE 'record: %; i: %', _rec, i;
      END LOOP;  -- inner loop
   END LOOP;  -- outer loop
END
$do$;

Related:

FOR loop on PLpgSQL function result
Postgres FOR LOOP

That said, more often than not, you can replace the whole shebang with a single SQL query ...
generate_series() - as recommended
You commented:

All I want is to iterate the single row into multiple rows based on the pays column value.

Then a very simple query can do the job:
SELECT *, generate_series(1, pays) AS loop
FROM   schema.table_name;

How!?
This equivalent, more explicit query should help to understand:
SELECT t.*, l.loop
FROM   schema.table_name t
CROSS  JOIN LATERAL generate_series(1, t.pays) l(loop);

Detailed explanation:

What is the difference between a LATERAL JOIN and a subquery in PostgreSQL?
Split column into multiple rows in Postgres
What is the expected behaviour for multiple set-returning functions in SELECT clause?


Thanks. will try this. Please let me know how to do this in a single query. All I want is to iterate the single row into multiple rows based on the pays column value. if the pays is 60 then the whole record should iterate 60 times then for next record if the pays is 1 it should be 1 record only. This should happen for the all the rows in the table

@user26533029: I added a set-based solution.
